# Laravel weird issue: query return data with DB::table() but not with model::

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I found an issue when delete some data, so I isolated the code

```
Route::get('v1/testapi', function (Request $request) {
return [
    DB::table('attendances')->select("id","attendance_date_id","remarks")
      ->whereIn('attendance_date_id', [925,926])->get(),
    Attendance::select("id","attendance_date_id","remarks")
      ->whereIn('attendance_date_id', [925,926])->get()
  ];
});
```

and this API always return

```
{
  "withDB":[
    {"id":8344,"attendance_date_id":925,"remarks":"Good"},
    {"id":8345,"attendance_date_id":925,"remarks":"Good"},
    {"id":8346,"attendance_date_id":925,"remarks":"Good"},
    {"id":8352,"attendance_date_id":926,"remarks":"Good"},
    {"id":8353,"attendance_date_id":926,"remarks":"Good"}
  ],
  "withModel":[]
}
```

Is there any difference between DB query and Model query?

NB: with or without `select("id","attendance_date_id","remarks")` it act same.

Comment: Does `Attendance` model return data without `whereIn` clause ? Like `Attendance::get()` or `Attendance::take(10)->get()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called **SoftDelete**. You have `deleted_at` column on your `Attendances` table. Laravel models have a trait called `SoftDeletes` so not only does it delete the record if this trait exits in the Model, but **Eloquent** sets the date on `deleted_at` column and doesn't show you this record.

On the other hand, the DB doesn't have this type of thing. It's like a normal query builder, and if it exists in the database, it just shows you. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) you can read more about soft delete.

Answer (score -2):

little extra detailes:
anyone can troubleshoot these type issues by enabling database query log like below

```
Route::get('v1/testapi', function (Request $request) {
  DB::enableQueryLog();
  return [
    'withDB'=>DB::table('attendances')->select("id","attendance_date_id","remarks")->whereIn('attendance_date_id', [925,926])->get(),
    'withModel'=>Attendance::select("id","attendance_date_id","remarks")->whereIn('attendance_date_id', [925,926])->get(),
    DB::getQueryLog()
  ];
});
```

and i found the query difference

```
{"query":"select `id`, `attendance_date_id`, `remarks` from `attendances` where `attendance_date_id` in (?, ?)","bindings":[925,926],"time":1.65},
{"query":"select `id`, `attendance_date_id`, `remarks` from `attendances` where `attendance_date_id` in (?, ?) and `attendances`.`deleted_at` is null","bindings":[925,926],"time":0.39}
```

the 'deleted_at' column make the issue

Comment: As I answered you. It is not an issue it is a feature of Laravel Eloquent Model. Can you mark my answer if it solved your question?

Comment: You can mark @gguney answer

Comment: @gguney forgot to mark, anyway already upvoted